# Generic CRUD application

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, dynamic

I want to create dynamic/generic CRUD application using Java8 which will connect to oracle database.

Firstly I started with [jdbc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/). All I had to do to work with database table was just typing table name. But when it came to work with relationships it started getting "buggy" and ugly.

I started looking for some higher than jdbc abstraction layer tool, but after hours of research I'm still not sure which one will fit my case.

At this moment I'm focusing on [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/), but as I can see there is no way to use it without *@Entity* classes that will describe my database tables. 
I was also strongly considering use [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/), but Open Source version doesn't support Oracle dialect.

**Question:** Is my case even possible to do with such genericity, so I just add table name and I can have working CRUD with all relations?

- If so, what can I use to help me achieve that and is that worth it?
- If not, is **Spring Data** good choice for me?

Comment: Spring Data is an excellent choice, especially if you already know Spring or Spring Boot.  You are correct - there is no way to use it without @Entity classes that will describe your database tables.  A higher abstraction does not seem possible, practical, or useful.

Comment: @duffymo So should I focus on some automatically generated `@Entity` classes and forget about generic CRUD without it?

Comment: You should worry about figuring out how JPA and Spring Data work before you try automatically generating classes.

Comment: Yes, I can see that figuring out how it actually works will be the most important part. I just want/ed to know if I will not "waste" time for something that cant help me out with my case.

Comment: You have a big hill to climb with JPA.  Worry about that.

Comment: Having working `CrudRepository` without `@Entity` is not possible. But to be honest: if you're having buggy or ugly relationships, there are not solved by going higher in level of abstraction. I'd rather go lower to plain old traditional sql, or fix the relations.

Comment: @membersound I wasnt meaning that relationships are ugly or buggy :) Just started to think that this project would be huge, and its always better to use something with support etc. Thats why Im thinking about giving up jdbc.

Comment: @duffymo Just to make sure, because still no one answered my question directly. Can I obtain such genericity using **Spring Data** as using plain **JDBC**? That's why there was a question about autamatically generating classses. I'm aware of how much I have to learn about JPA.

Comment: I honestly don't know why you're so obsessed with generics.  Of course it's possible to do it in JDBC - that's how the Spring Data and JPA people did it.  It's not trivial.  It may not even be desirable.  You may be guilty of putting too much emphasis on a requirement that is peripheral to solving your problem.  Do it as best you can with JDBC and learn from it.